# Exclude a directory from getting zipped using zipfile module in python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to zip  a directory using python zipfile module and its working well.But now i want to exclude some folders.ie if  my director tree is like

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
```

then i want to archive all to myfile.zip but excluding "ghi"

I am trying to zip files using

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("Application server.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("D:\\review docs"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

so this is archiving everything under "D:\review docs" to "Application server.zip" but i want to exclude some directories from the zip.
In fact i can use linux commands to do the same but i want to use zipfile module.
Also if i pop exclude folder name from "dirname" list optained from os.walk,will that work?
further Adding up a  check before zipping like if "dirname"=="exlude folder" will also work i think but i want a neat solution of doing the same using the module.I read some where that   zipfile module provides this functionality but didn't found any code example for the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes , you can remove elements from the subdirs , that would make sure that os.walk() does not into those directories. Example -

```
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("D:\\review docs"):
    if 'exclude directory' in subdirs:
        subdirs.remove('exclude directory')
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. How does it exclude "ghi"?

Comment: If you remove something from the 'subdirs' (second parameter) of os.walk() , os.walk() does not walk into it , that way that entire directory will be skipped. Details at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a more complete version, which being able to filter folders and exts

We can't simply delete the folder like .svn before zipping. The following code can help.

It zips a folder to a zip file, maintaining its structure and filtering certain folders and exts, like what you expect natually.

```
def IsPathValid(path, ignoreDir, ignoreExt):
    splited = None
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if ignoreExt:
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
            if ext in ignoreExt:
                return False

        splited = os.path.dirname(path).split('\\/')
    else:
        if not ignoreDir:
            return True
        splited = path.split('\\/')

    if ignoreDir:
        for s in splited:
            if s in ignoreDir:  # You can also use set.intersection or [x for],
                return False

    return True


def zipDirHelper(path, rootDir, zf, ignoreDir=None, ignoreExt=None):
    # zf is zipfile handle
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if IsPathValid(path, ignoreDir, ignoreExt):
            relative = os.path.relpath(path, rootDir)
            zf.write(path, relative)
        return

    ls = os.listdir(path)
    for subFileOrDir in ls:
        if not IsPathValid(subFileOrDir, ignoreDir, ignoreExt):
            continue

        joinedPath = os.path.join(path, subFileOrDir)
        zipDirHelper(joinedPath, rootDir, zf, ignoreDir, ignoreExt)


def ZipDir(path, zf, ignoreDir=None, ignoreExt=None, close=False):
    rootDir = path if os.path.isdir(path) else os.path.dirname(path)

    try:
        zipDirHelper(path, rootDir, zf, ignoreDir, ignoreExt)
    finally:
        if close:
            zf.close()
```

use it like this:

```
import zipfile
theZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(targetZipFile, 'w')
Util.ZipDir(target_dir, theZipFile, ignoreDir=[".svn"], ignoreExt=[".zip"], close=True)
# If you like to zip more files, just close=False and manually close the file or use "with xxx" on your own
```